# Android Variable Usage within Classes

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I have a class within my Activity and I can not use the variables in the subclass in the Activity class. Why is this happening?!

This is in the subclass:

```
       try 
            {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                String jsonData = builder.toString();
                Log.e("Data", jsonData);
                person = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                email = person.getString("email");


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("No Data", "Nothing");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("No Data", "Nothing");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("EMAIL", email);
            return null;
        }
```

I get the right value of email in my Log.e output but when I try to assign my text view the string email in the activity class, it wont work and crashes the emulator.

```
  TextView myEmailView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15); 
  myEmailView.setText(email);
```

Comment: You would have to post the relevant parts of the class and indicate the problem variables for any help. Otherwise, this question doesn't have enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: You should post the logcat from the crash. Also, you don't show where/how you are trying to access the `TextView`. Is this in a background `Thread`, I hope since you are doing networking? You most likely want to declare the `TextView` as a member variable and make sure you are calling `setText()` on the main `Thread`.

Comment: Also, by "subclass", do you mean inner-class?

Comment: I have a class that gets parses the json which is the subclass. Yeah it is an inner class of my Activity.  I can not use the values received from the json in that class in my activity class where I set the text of the textview

Comment: Post the logcat. Also, is the code you posted in an `AsyncTask`? It would probably be easier if it was.

Comment: yes it is in an Async. I changed the code a bit now trying to make it work but the logcat was giving me errors about runtime and null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Then you need **to post the logcat**.